# Slow down the mouse

Tags: 18.04, mouse, system-settings

I have a ThinkPad with a TrackPoint (the little "mouse" nub in the center of the keyboard. While I prefer this method of mousing, it requires a slower mouse speed than other types of mice.

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04, the mouse has been too fast (my previous settings were lost in the upgrade). I can't seem to find a way to slow it down.

Things I've tried based on searching AskUbuntu:

1. Mouse settings. I've set the slider to its lowest setting, but it isn't slow enough.
2. `xinput --set-prop "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" "libinput Accel Speed" -1`. This is basically the same as the first one. `xinput` only accepts a numbers between -1 and 1. So, I've got it at the slowest speed it accepts. *Aside: Zero should mean "mouse doesn't move," so that all speeds are possible. Allowing negative speeds doesn't even make sense.*
3. `xset m`. Setting this has no effect whatsoever, regardless of the values I use.

It appears to me that the xinput and xset tools just don't work on a modern Ubuntu. However, if I could find the setting that the mouse settings tool tweaks, that one actually does seem to work. So, I'm looking for an answer to one or both of these questions:

1. How can I manually (from the command line or a configuration file) adjust the mouse speed settings as configured from the main settings app?
2. What other methods are available to adjust the mouse settings which either don't rely on xinput and/or xset or persuade the system to actually follow their settings?

Comment: might be useful: https://www.reddit.com/r/Trackballs/comments/9yfqaq/ubuntu_1604_and_logitech_m570/ it restore evdev driver